# Why is Spotify iOS SDK hanging indefinitely on SPTAudioStreamingController.login()?

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

Following is the code snippet that is hanging:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                log.info("User is a premium user. Logging into player.")
                self.player?.login(withAccessToken: self.session!.accessToken)
                log.info("Logged into player.")
            }
```

A few notes:

- The user is logged in with a premium user account, and a valid oauth token.
- In a previous codebase, this worked.
- It's running on main.async because in a previous codebase where this worked, I was running on that DispatchQueue.
- Running it on the same thread, without the `async {}` doesn't work either.
- Creating a new DispatchQueue, running it on the queue as async, also doesn't work.
- According to the debugger, it's hanging on the subcall `SPTAudioStreamingController.dispatchToAudioThread`.

Any help, or even just long-shot ideas on what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what version of the sdk are you using? Have you tried not specifying the thread?

Comment: In the non-working version, I am using 0.25.0. I am not certain about the version in the working code, but it may be older. I have tried not specifying the thread, no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing a call before login that is important. You need to first call the `start(withClientId: )` method.

```
  do {
    try self.player?.start(withClientId: clientID)
  } catch {
    log("Failed to start with clientId")
  }
```

In the documentation, calling the start method:

> "Start the `SPAudioStreamingController` thread with the default
>   audioController."

Which explains why it would hang on the `dispatchToAudioThread`